# How to exclude a controller from being authenticated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, action-filter

I have overriden the IautheticationFIlter in my asp.net web api project. Here is my class:

```
public class TokenAuthentication : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private readonly string realm;

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

    public TokenAuthentication(string realm)
    {
        this.realm = "realm=" + realm;
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        // Receive token from the client. Here is the example when token is in header:
        var token = request.Headers.GetValues("Token").ElementAt(0);

        ...

        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }


    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = new ResultWithChallenge(context.Result, realm);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Now I need to exclude my login controller from being authenticated:

Curently when I run my project every request trtiggers this code if i put [Authorize],  [AllowAnonymous] or no filters at all.

Here is where I add the filter:

```
      public static void RegisterHttpFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {           
        filters.Add(new TokenAuthentication(""));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you mix up *authentication* and *authorization*. Probably you want to exclude your login controller from being authorized.
 [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes are used in the authorization context and have nothing to do with authentication. That's why your IAuthenticationFilter is called every time.
This article could be useful as well http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api.

Comment: I am combining my authorization and authentication in one. I am using a JWT token with my userId encrypted in the token. So every request (once logged in) will have a token in the headers. but they need to login first. I have no roles based authentication, So i hope you see my issue?

Comment: I believe there might be some confusion here. There is no roles based authentication. Roles are used for authorization. I suggest to separate the concerns (authorization and authentication). This separation is the reason why the IAuthenticationFilter were implemented in MVC 5. Anyway, this article could be helpful <http://jameschambers.com/2013/11/working-with-iauthenticationfilter-in-the-mvc-5-framework>.

Comment: This article about *authorization* could be interesting as well   <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx> . You could probably use a similar approach for authentication.